# Send an email via php from my laptop

Tags: php

**UPDATE 1:**

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and installed the default LAMP stack.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am using my laptop as a development machine.  Is it possible for me to send an email from my laptop using php?

I am using LAMP on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, just install and configure an MTA (Postfix, sendmail, Exim, ...) on your laptop (since you're on Linux) that has a sendmail wrapper and change your php.ini settings accordingly. You can find tutorials on how to set this up for a lot of Linux distributions on http://howtoforge.com/.

If you need more specific info, you should at least mention the Linux distribution (and version of it) that you use.

Comment: Then the easiest install method probably is `sudo apt-get install postfix`, `sudo apt-get install sendmail` or `sudo apt-get install exim` (depending on your preference) in CLI, and follow the prompts to enter the basic info. It might work out of the box (just test it), if not you will have to start tweaking the settings (which can vary based on your ISP). If I were you I'd just setup a basic relay which forwards mails to your ISP mail server.

Comment: I've tried `sudo aptitude install sendmail` but still can't use sendmail from php even after restarting apache2.  So I think you're right by saying I need to configure it.

Comment: You might be better off installing Postfix, refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix for more info.

Comment: @wimvds, that a lot to do to get postfix to work, do I really need to do all that even for localhost development for testing email messages?  Anywa, how would I do basic relaying which forwards mails to my isp mail server?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Just install postfix with default settings, and then add/edit the `relayhost` line in /etc/postfix/main.cf so it points to your ISP mail server (ie. `relayhost = mail.yourprovider.com`). Then just restart postfix and you should be good to go (if not then it could be that you will need some of the extra configuration settings to setup SMTP Auth). One gently reminder though : *only* do this on your development machine, don't do it on a server :p.

Comment: BTW Here are the steps needed to setup SMTP auth with relaying (once postfix is installed), just in case : http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-relay-email-on-a-postfix-server.

Comment: Is it possible to use gmail as the relayhost?  Yep, only planning to do this on the development machine.  Will get it properly configured by professionals on the live server.

Comment: If your ISP allows external SMTP servers, then yes. But keep in mind that some ISPs block access to external mail hosts, effectively forcing you to use their servers instead. Anyway, here's how you set up relaying to gmail : [Relaying Postfix SMTP via smtp.gmail.com](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/11/11/relaying-postfix-smtp-via-smtpgmailcom/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can send mail via the `sendmail` command, you can try the [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function. Otherwise you may want to use some mail libraries for PHP, phpmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or swift mailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) for instance.

I personally use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [php mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

That could help immensely

Comment: Don't I need some sort of mail server running in the background?

Comment: if you are on a lamp box, you shouldnt, windows u need to set that up

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to send an email from your laptop using PHP.

Comment: Don't I need some sort of mail server running in the background?